# How to correctly use multiple user model in django?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

Good day, I got the following models, but I believe there's a better way to achieve what I have done. My worry is about extending the GeneralUser, I'm not really finding it a great idea.
Is it good to extend the GeneralUser as I'm currently doing, or will it be better to create a foreignkey to the GeneralUser in all models where I want to reference it?

```
class GeneralUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=choices)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()


 class Administrator(GeneralUser):
    admin_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Patient(GeneralUser):
    patient_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Doctor(GeneralUser):
    doctor_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Department(models.Model):
    doctor_id = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='doctor')

class Bill(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='patient')


class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='patient')
    doctor_id = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='doctor')

class PatientRecord(models.Model):
    pass


class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(help_text='name@domain.com')
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, help_text='+27 074 859 81 93')
    message = models.TextField(help_text='Please, type in your message')
```

Any help or thought on how to make better design the tables and relationships ?

Comment: why you don't handle this with groups ?

Comment: @mtt2p not sure of how to do it with group

Comment: I'm just trying to have a better way of playing with inheritances in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that fits so !
(OneToOneField is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=False,editable=False)

class Distributor(UserProfile):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  '%s <%s>' % (self.user.username, self.company) 

class Customer(UserProfile):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    limit = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank=True, null=True , editable=False)
    distributor = models.ForeignKey(Distributor,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return  ("%s <%s>" % (self.user.username, self.company))
```

Comment: that's the point check your distributor and customer they've so many fields in common could have been better if they're in UserProfile